# Rollup and eslint : How can I fix this error "TypeError: eslint is not a function" using eslint with rollup?

Tags: eslint, rollup

I'm trying to use rollup for the first time and I can't figure out why I get this error :

```
TypeError: eslint is not a function
```

I previously installed rollup (v1.1.0) then eslint `npm install rollup-plugin-eslint` (v5.0.0)

here is my rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import eslint from 'rollup-plugin-eslint';

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        format: 'iife',
        file: 'build/js/main.min.js',
        name: 'main'
    },
    plugins: [
        eslint({
            exclude: [
                'src/styles/**',
            ]
        }),
        babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        }),
    ],
}
```

When I use `./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c` I get this error `TypeError: eslint is not a function`. (NB : rollup is working fine with only babel)

However it works if I use `npm run lint` adding this code in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src/**"
  }
```

What do I do wrong with the rollup configuration ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing:

```
- import eslint from 'rollup-plugin-eslint';
+ import { eslint } from 'rollup-plugin-eslint';
```

[Release notes for v5.0.0](https://github.com/TrySound/rollup-plugin-eslint/releases/tag/v5.0.0)